# How to update a value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I'm trying to fill an array with empty objects and then update them.

```
let arr = new Array(2).fill({test: undefined});

console.log(arr)

for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    arr[i].test = "sample" + i
}

console.log(arr)
```

**Expected output:**

First print:

> (2) [{…}, {…}] 0: {test: undefined} 1: {test: undefined}

Second Print

> (2) [{…}, {…}] 0: {test: sample0} 1: {test: sample1}

**Instead, what I get in both cases is:**

> (2) [{…}, {…}] 0: {test: "sample1"} 1: {test: "sample1"}

Why is the whole array overwritten each iteration and how could I get the desired output?

Comment: The object that is being used to "fill" may be reused for all array indexes.  If so, setting one will change all of them, as they are the same element.

Comment: @HynekS that is only an issue when execution of the contents of the for-loop are deferred in any way (like an async function)

Comment: Use .map(()=>({test: undefined}))

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by assigning new arr.

```
let arr = new Array(2).fill({test: undefined});

let new_arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  new_arr.push({test: `Sample ${i}`})
}
console.log(new_arr);
```